# Is there a way to preload an image used as a CSS background image so when there is no connection it can still be displayed?

Tags: javascript, css

Scenario:

I have a web application that displays as an error dialogue when an action is performed but cannot be completed because of a connection issue.

A CSS class for this dialogue has a background image, but because there is a connection issue it cannot load, thus the dialogue looks strange.

Is there a way to preload the image so even if there is no connection the image is available?

Comment: Data URIs: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) / [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

Answer (score 0):

You can register the service and put image in cache. Whenever image request arrive you can respond with the image in cache.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers